# WinAPI LoadKeyboardLayout();

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard-layout

I compile dll with VS2010 but I have problems with changing keyboard layout. I am running Windows 7.

```
GetKeyboardLayout(0); //Returns previous layout
LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", KLF_ACTIVATE);
GetKeyboardLayout(0); //Returns 04090409 (English layout)
```

But the layout is NOT changed. One may say that I am doing something wrong but if I change "00000409" to any other language ID for example to russian "00000419" layout is changed perfectly. The problem occurs only with English layout.

The same problem occur when I use `ActivateKeyboardLayout` when all layouts are switched ok but english don't work.

What king of problem it can be?

Comment: Have you tried calling GetLastError after LoadKeyboardLayout?

Comment: `But the layout is changed`.  Good, no problem?

Comment: GetLastError() is 0 in both cases. Furthermore `GetKeyboardLayout` Before Layout F0C00422
After Layout 04090409 Error 0. So it has changed but in reality it hasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug made my day. Everything work OK after reboot.